# Apache: RewriteRule leads to segfault

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I use a RewriteRule to replace all spaces (aka %20) in my URLs by underscores:

```
RewriteRule (.*)[\ ](.*) $1_$2 [N]
```

The [N] flag starts the rewrite process again, until no space is left (hopefully). Now, all is well, when there is a file waiting at the other side, i.e. request:

```
/This is an example.html
```

and file:

```
This_is_an_example.html
```

But when there is no matching file, Apache exits with a 500 Internal Error. The error log states a segfault, and the rewrite log shows, that the rewrite engine goes mad trying to redirect to

```
/This is an_example.html/This is an_example.html/This is an_example.html/...
```

and so on until the segfault (note, that the *last* space was converted, but none else).

Has anyone an idea, why the RewriteRule fails so miserably, while working for existing files?

**Update:** The segfault only occurs, if there is an additional "/" in the requested URI, like

```
/virtual-directory/This is an example.html
```

**Update 2:** There is *no* RewriteCond in this statement. In my opinion it should work without. The question is, why doesn't it. Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule (.*)[\ ](.*) $1_$2 [N]
```

**Update 3:** The .htaccess file in question:

```
AddType application/xhtml+xml .xhtml
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 1 year"

ErrorDocument 404 /test/index.php?error=404

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test/

# replace spaces with underscores
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*[\ ].*
RewriteRule (.*)[\ ](.*) $1_$2 [N]

# the index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]

# language tag
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1&url= [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ en [R=301,L]

# add .xhtml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.xhtml -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.xhtml.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.xhtml

# add .gz
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} .*gzip.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz

# send correct mime type
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule \.xhtml\.gz$  - [L,T=application/xhtml+xml]
```

The rewriteLog statements are too large to paste. A single request fills the file with 13MB of data. Here is the digest:

```
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] add path info postfix: /htdocs/test/de -> /htdocs/test/de/This is a test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /htdocs/test/de/This is a test -> de/This is a test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] applying pattern '(.*)[\ ](.*)' to uri 'de/This is a test'
(IP) - - [date] [host] (2) [perdir /htdocs/test/] rewrite 'de/This is a test' -> 'de/This is a_test'
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] add per-dir prefix: de/This is a_test -> /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] add path info postfix: /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test -> /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test/This is a test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test/This is a test -> de/This is a_test/This is a test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] applying pattern '(.*)[\ ](.*)' to uri 'de/This is a_test/This is a test'
(IP) - - [date] [host] (2) [perdir /htdocs/test/] rewrite 'de/This is a_test/This is a test' -> 'de/This is a_test/This is a_test'
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] add per-dir prefix: de/This is a_test/This is a_test -> /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test/This is a_test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] add path info postfix: /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test/This is a_test -> /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a test -> de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a test
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] applying pattern '(.*)[\ ](.*)' to uri 'de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a test'
(IP) - - [date] [host] (2) [perdir /htdocs/test/] rewrite 'de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a test' -> 'de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a_test'
(IP) - - [date] [host] (3) [perdir /htdocs/test/] add per-dir prefix: de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a_test -> /htdocs/test/de/This is a_test/This is a_test/This is a_test
... and so on ad infinitum
```

The bad guy is line 6: "add path info postfix".

Comment: how and where do define your `/virtual-directory` (or is it `/test`)?

Comment: and what is your [ErrorDocument][1] in effect in `/virtual-directory`?

 [1]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: I updated the question accordingly. ErrorDocument is only defined for 404s, it's a redirect to an index.php in the same directory as the .htaccess file. The "/virtual-directory" is in real life the language prefix (like "/en/" or "/de/") I use to distinguish the requested language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

looking at your *update 3* (helpful, thanks), 2 more ideas come to my mind:

1. there is an apache issue: [*mod_rewrite adds path info postfix after a substitution occured*](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38642), that looks similar to yours. this was [fixed in 2.2.12](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2) with the introduction of the [`discardpathinfo|DPI` RewriteRule flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags). try adding this flag to your `RewriteRule`:

   ```
   RewriteRule (.*)[\ ](.*) $1_$2 [N,DPI]
   ```

   and see if that solves the issue. needs apache 2.2.12.
2. do you happen to have [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) enabled an [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)`On`? try disabling it.

**UPDATE END**

your setup:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*[\ ].*
RewriteRule (.*)[\ ](.*) $1_$2 [N]
```

works for me (`http://localhost/test/This is an example.html`, rewrite rules in `VirtualHost` config, apache 2.2.14). here is my `RewriteLog` (with `RewriteLogLevel 2`):

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/This is an example.html
rewrite '/test/This is an example.html' -> '/test/This is an_example.html'
rewrite '/test/This is an_example.html' -> '/test/This is_an_example.html'
rewrite '/test/This is_an_example.html' -> '/test/This_is_an_example.html'
local path result: /test/This_is_an_example.html
prefixed with document_root to D:/var/www/test/This_is_an_example.html
go-ahead with D:/var/www/test/This_is_an_example.html [OK]
```

when `D:/var/www/test/This_is_an_example.html` does not exist, i get a `404` - but no segfault.

could you post your `RewriteLog`? where do you put your rewrite rules? into an `.htaccess`? do you have any directives (`AliasMatch` etc.) that also work on your url?

Comment: It works for me too, when I add the RewriteCond. The question however is, why do I need the RewriteCond at all? If you look at my RewriteRule in the question, it should loop round and round until no space is left, and that without need of a RewriteCond. My question is, why doesn't it do it.

Comment: it also works here without the `RewriteCond` (same `RewriteLog`). so again: what does your `RewriteLog` look like, are your rewrite rules in an `.htaccess`, and/or are there other directives matching the url in question?

Comment: The rewrite rules are in an .htaccess file. Please note my first update in the question, the segfault only occurs, if there is a folder-like component before the rule. I'll paste a bit of the rewrite log above into the question.

Comment: Wow, thanks for digging up the bug. It really looks like my problem. Unfortunately I still have 2.2.11, but I'll try and set up 2.2.12 to verify this, before the bounty expires.

Comment: Yep, that bug was the problem. Now I'm gonna print out this question, frame it and put it on the wall. In the end, how many mod_rewrite questions on SO end with: "It's not your fault, it's a bug in mod_rewrite"? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try an absolute replacement:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\ ]*)\ (.*) /$1_$2 [N]
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work, same result. I circumvent it now with a condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*[\ ].*`

Answer (score 0):

By and large, the Apache developers will take a SIGSEGV in httpd quite seriously if presented with a repeatable test case. Even more so if you attach a debugger and capture a backtrace.

Comment: the segfault could probably be disabled with LimitInternalRecursion (Apache 2.0.47+) or RewriteOptions MaxRedirects (2.0.45-46)